# Mesmo comando não funciona em outro servidor (discord.js) (node.js) v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Estou fazendo um comando para todas as vezes que um usuário reagir em "⚔️", o bot dá um cargo pra ele. Só que tem um detalhe: O cargo é dependente. Se o número de pessoas com o cargo `oi` no servidor for maior do que o número de pessoas com o cargo `ossete`, o bot dá o cargo `ossete`. Caso contrário, ele dá o role `oi`.

O código rodou perfeitamente no meu servidor de testes com **10 membros**:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client( {
       intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
       partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });

const config = require("./config.json");

var idoi = "958034784905461760"
var idsete = "958034846259753031"
var mensagem = "957993517655928903"

client.on('messageReactionAdd' , async (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.partial)   {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Ih, não consegui achar a reação...', error); return;
        }
    }

    let servidor = reaction.message.guild
    if(reaction.message.id !==  mensagem ) return;
    if(reaction._emoji.name !== '⚔️') return;

    let oi = servidor.roles.cache.get(idoi)
    let ossete = servidor.roles.cache.get(idsete)
    const member = servidor.members.cache.get(user.id);
        await servidor.members.fetch()

                if(member.roles.cache.has(idoi)) return;
                if(member.roles.cache.has(idsete)) return;
                if(ossete.members.size >= oi.members.size){
                    member.roles.add(oi)};

                if(oi.members.size > ossete.members.size) { member.roles.add(ossete) }
                    
            })

client.on = console.log('Estou pronto!'),

client.login(token aqui)
```

Ele deu exatamente o que eu pedi. Até agora beleza. Só que assim que eu adiciono meu bot a um servidor que tenho cargo administrativo de **20k membros**, o bot retorna o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\---\Desktop\Boto\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:320
      this.client.on(Events.GUILD_MEMBERS_CHUNK, handler);
                  ^

TypeError: this.client.on is not a function
    at C:\Users\---\Desktop\Boto\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:320:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GuildMemberManager._fetchMany (C:\Users\---\Desktop\Boto\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:272:12)
    at GuildMemberManager.fetch (C:\Users\---\Desktop\Boto\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:124:31)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\---\Desktop\Boto\bot.js:96:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Coisa que não acontecia antes!

Eu ativei as `Intents` no site do Discord Developers, mas deu na mesma. Qual será o passo a seguir?

Obs: (Claro que eu adaptei os IDs no código assim que mudei de servidor)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá! O erro no código, ao que parece, se resume à linha `client.on = console.log('Estou pronto!'),`.

Ao definir `client.on` como `console.log('Estou pronto!')`, você remove o atributo original da função `client.on()`, oriunda da livraria Discord.js.

Deve-se remover a linha e substituí-la pelo seguinte bloco:

```
client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready: bot is online")
})
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Demorei muito pra achar o erro quando vi que tinha feito um erro de principiante. Não me toquei!! Vi isso agora também kkkkkkkkkkk